# Flutter get video frames using video player or ffmpeg

Tags: flutter, dart, ffmpeg

I have a flutter app that processes videos, now, I want to display like a video timeline at the bottom of the video but it should be comprised of the video frames of the video at various points, my googling has been fruitless so far and I was hoping to achieve this using flutter [video_player](https://pub.dev/packages/video_player) and/or [flutter_ffmpeg](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_ffmpeg) (I use these packages in my app). I have tried to look this online but I want to avoid using another package just for this, how do i achieve this using either or both the packages?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi there, I'm trying to build something quite similar to this, have you had any luck figuring out a solution.

Comment: @DevonRay look at the answer

Answer (score 4):

I actually found a work around, I decided better find something that's already working than reinvent the wheel. So the plugin [video_thumbnail](https://pub.dev/packages/video_thumbnail) to the resque, look at how it is being used here [github](https://github.com/sbis04/video_trimmer/blob/master/lib/src/thumbnail_viewer.dart). I hope this will save someone the headache too.

Comment: sorry for asking stupid question, but I would like to know if  you have tried to implement something like a video archive and the ability to put timestamps on the video and rewind 1 hour, 3 hours, 15 days back or more? I'm currently struggling with the same task and my video should come from the internet in live mode. Have this package  video_thumbnail  can solve this issue? I was recommended to use together both video_player and flutter_ffmpeg , but I am not sure... Just would like to know someone expireince too

Comment: first, no, not stupic question, second, actually this was my first project handling videos and i was just experimenting wanting to come up with something cool, so no, i haven't tried any of the stuff you mentioned but i have used the libraries. I sort of abandoned the project coz i got busy but i might pick it up again and continue experimenting

Comment: oh, thanks you for answering. It is also my project which l am trying to make something cool, but currently it doesn't look like anything good. it would be cool if someday you could return to your project. Thanks again. I would loom more closely to the github link you posted above